# Why doesn't netstat show me some ports?

Tags: tcp, netstat, nmap

When port-scanning my computer with another machine, I find three open ports:

```
Starting Nmap 7.40 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-05-08 22:14 CEST
Nmap scan report for laptop.local (192.168.11.103)
Host is up (0.00023s latency).
Not shown: 64998 closed ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
22/tcp    open  ssh
1716/tcp  open  xmsg
22000/tcp open  snapenetio

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 14.62 seconds
```

`netstat` (from [net-tools](http://net-tools.sourceforge.net/), version 1.60; run as root) on the machine itself however doesn't show 1716 and 22000:

```
# netstat -lnt 
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

I know that [syncthing](http://syncthing) listens on 22000, and [KDEConnect](https://community.kde.org/KDEConnect) listens on 1716. But why doesn't netstat list these ports?

What would I need to do to find out which processes are attached to ports 22000 and 1716?

Comment: It may not be anything on the machine that has those ports open, but on an intermediate router.

Comment: There's no router between the machine I was running nmap on and the host. They're in the same subnet.

Comment: Run `nmap` on the host itself, with `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: It also shows 22000 and 1716 as open.

Comment: Look at `/proc/net/tcp`; the `local_address` column shows hex-encoded IP:port.

Comment: Doesn't show up there, `cat /proc/net/tcp | grep 55F0` (0x55F0 == 22000) returns an empty result. Same for 0x06B4 (1716)